# How to make the sql stored procedure return the values of two or more tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that retrieves a list of Advisers. the Advisers table has "CreatedById" column that is foreign keyed to Users.UserId table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAdvisers
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @AdviserId int = 0
    ,@EmployeeNo nvarchar(100) = ''
    ,@LastName nvarchar(100) = ''
    ,@FirstName nvarchar(100) = ''
    ,@MiddleName nvarchar(100) = ''

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT ISNULL(I.AdviserId,0) as AdviserId
      ,ISNULL(I.EmployeeNo, '') as EmployeeNo
      ,ISNULL(I.LastName, '') as LastName
      ,ISNULL(I.FirstName, '') as FirstName
      ,ISNULL(I.MiddleName, '') as MiddleName
      ,ISNULL(I.StatId, 0) as StatId
      ,ISNULL(I.CreatedById, 0) as CreatedById
      ,ISNULL(U.UserName, '') as CreatedByName
      ,ISNULL(I.CreatedOn, null) as CreatedOn

    FROM Advisers I

        LEFT JOIN Users U ON U.UserId = I.CreatedById

    WHERE (I.AdviserId = @AdviserId OR @AdviserId = 0)
      AND (I.EmployeeNo LIKE '%' + @EmployeeNo +'%' OR @EmployeeNo = '')     
      AND I.StatId <> 2 

END

GO
```

but in my code behind, the User property is null. How can I make the SQL return the User as well?

here is my Adviser class (auto generated from entity framework)

```
public partial class Adviser
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Adviser()
        {
            this.GradeSections = new HashSet<GradeSection>();
        }

        public int AdviserId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreatedById { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Stat Stat { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<GradeSection> GradeSections { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my adviser data access layer:

```
public class AdviserDb 
    {
        public List<Adviser> GetList(AdviserP p, ref string msgLog)
        {
            ProcessLog processLog;
            var command = new SqlCommand();
            List<Adviser> items = new List<Adviser>();
            msgLog = "";
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "GetAdvisers";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdviserId", p.AdviserId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNo", p.EmployeeNo).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", p.MiddleName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);

                if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return items;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Adviser item = new Adviser();
                    item.User = new User();

                    item.AdviserId = row["AdviserId"].GetInt();
                    item.EmployeeNo = row["EmployeeNo"].GetString();
                    item.LastName = row["LastName"].GetString();
                    item.FirstName = row["FirstName"].GetString();
                    item.MiddleName = row["MiddleName"].GetString();
                    item.StatId = row["StatId"].GetInt();
                    item.Stat.Name = row["StatName"].GetString(); // this is also null
                    item.CreatedById = row["CreatedById"].GetInt(); 
                    item.User.UserName = row["CreatedByName"].GetString(); // why is this null?
                    item.CreatedOn = row["CreatedOn"].GetDbDate();

                    items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException s)
            {
                processLog = new ProcessLog(new SqlErrorLogger());
                msgLog = processLog.GenerateProcessLog(s.Message);
            }

            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the stored procedure directly in SSMS?

Comment: You can join Advisers and Users tables with on(CreatedById=UserId ) and get the data.

Comment: @Zohar Peled, yup. it worked fine. just the nulled item.Stat.Name = row["StatName"].GetString(); and item.User.UserName = row["CreatedByName"].GetString(); is the problem.

Comment: @Chandan, I already did that on user
LEFT JOIN Users U ON U.UserId = I.CreatedById

Comment: "StatName" does not appear on the query at all, only in the c# code. "CreatedByName", however, still remains a mystery for now...

Comment: i removed it to focus on Users

Comment: Try to run in debug more and look directly at the data table.